# how do I filter what I entered in the JTextField and display the filtered result?

Tags: java, string, jframe, jtextfield, indexoutofboundsexception

```
package javaisnotbannana;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class  Javaisnotbannana{

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        window();
    }       
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static void window()
    {
     JFrame window= new JFrame();
     JPanel jp = new JPanel();
     JLabel jl = new JLabel();
     JTextField jt = new JTextField(30);
     JButton jb = new JButton("Enter");
     window.setTitle("ThisisTitleofWindow");
     window.setVisible(true);
     window.setSize(500, 500);
     window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     //textfield
     jp.add(jt);
     jt.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
     {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
     String inoutt = jt.getText();

     jl.setText(inoutt); 
     }
     });
```

Why dose this lower section have the problem "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:(how ever many characters i entered)".str is receiving what is typed in the Jtextfield and im trying to filter the input to give a different output. With out a filter it works fine like above just press enter,but when i try to press the button i and filter i get an error.

```
//button
     jp.add(jb);
     jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
     {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
     String str = jt.getText();
     String text="";
     int A=0;
     int B=1;
     int C=2;
     for(int num=0;num<=str.length()/3;num++)
        {
            if (str.charAt(A) == 'T'&&str.charAt(B) == 'A'&&str.charAt(C)=='S')
            {
            text+="smell tasty";
            }
            else if(str.charAt(A) == 'B'&&str.charAt(B) == 'A'&&str.charAt(C)=='N')
            {
            text+="bannanas";
            }
            A+=3;
            B+=3;
            C+=3;
        }
     jl.setText(text);
     }
     });
     jp.add(jl);
     window.add(jp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the line number, the string thats being operated on, the string index it's trying to hit. Does the index look appropriate? I suspect that it's because A, B or C becomes >= the length of the string.

Comment: it is this line that has the error "for(int num=0;num<=str.length()/3;num++)" and i know the error isn't because its the length of the string because it works above with no error and it would finish the for loop if its equal.

Comment: Are you sure it's not happening on the `if (str.charAt(A) == 'T'&&str.charAt(B) == 'A'&&str.charAt(C)=='S')` line? :S

Comment: `if ("tas".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) { text = "smell tasty"; }` or some such?

Comment: it says that im going out of bounds by how ever many i enter so  String str = jt.getText(); might be making str nothing but it should make it equal the text i entered.

Comment: if ("tas".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) { text = "smell tasty"; } gives me the message twice and gives me the other case bannanas once just typing in tas.

Comment: now i fell dumb thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your index is overshooting use this instead

```
for(int num=0;num<str.length()/3;num++)
```

just < not <=

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to the fact that you are overthinking the it.  Remember, Java `String`s are zero indexed so `num<=str.length()/3` should be something more like `num < str.length()/3`

But, having said that, the whole thing seems woefully inefficient (not to mention confusing)

You could use something like...

```
for (int num = 0; num + 3 < str.length(); num++) {
    String test = str.substring(num, 3);
    if ("tas".equalsIgnoreCase(test)) {
        text = "smell tasty";
        break;
    } else if ("ban".equalsIgnoreCase(test)) {
        text = "bannanas";
        break;
    }
}
```

But even that's a long way around an otherwise simple problem.

Instead, you could simply use something like...

```
String str = "tas";
String text = "";
if (str.toLowerCase().contains("tas")) {
  text = "smell tasty";
} else if (str.toLowerCase().contains("ban")) {
  text = "bannanas";
}
```